# How to parse the date time string including the milliseconds using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to convert a datatime string "including milliseconds" into a DataTime. I tried tried to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` but it does not give me a milliseconds.

Here is what I have tired

```
public static DateTime? dateTimeVal(string raw, string format = null)
{
    DateTime final;

    if(raw != null){

        if( format != null){

            string[] formats = new[] { format };  

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(raw, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out final))
            {
                return final;
            }
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParse(raw, out final))
        {
            return final;
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

This is how I use the method above

```
DateTime? dt = dateTimeVal("2016-03-14 11:22:21.352", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

However, dt gives me this `3/14/2016 11:22:21 AM`

How can I get the value to include the milliseconds?

Comment: How are you verifying if the result is correct?  Are you printing the value?  Logging it?  Using Console.WriteLine?  Can you show the code you are using to check the result?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime final = new DateTime();
var test = DateTime.TryParseExact("2016-03-14 11:22:21.352", new string[] { "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out final);
```

This works for me.

[image]

Just take care for your `fff`. If you write them uppercase, the milliseconds will be supressed. Lowercase they will be parsed.

The only thing away from that I can imagine is you have used `.ToString` without providing any format. Then you'll get:

[image]

Are you sure you've written the providing format lowercase inside your code? Also have you used `.ToString()` with an output-format that shows up the milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `DateTime` as `string` with `milisecond`, then you can use the following code;

```
string dateTime = dt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want the end value to be a string. I want it to be a DataTime

Comment: @MikeA then you can use dt.Value.Millisecond property.