# C#: Set DateTime format in ASP.NET response?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say I have an entity like so:

```
public class Event
{
    public Event(DateTime happenedAt)
    {
        HappenedAt = happenedAt;
    }
    
    public DateTime HappenedAt { get; }
}
```

I'm returning it via ASP.NET like so:

```
return Ok(new Event(DateTime.Parse("2023-04-09 09:35:19.527")));
```

On the backend timestamps are returned like `"2023-04-09T09:35:19"`, cutting out the `.fff` or micro seconds. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: This should help u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995569/how-to-parse-the-date-time-string-including-the-milliseconds-using-c

Answer (score 0):

Use `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I've tried this but it still cuts off the end result.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Did you test [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0) ?

```
DateTime eventDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2023-04-09 09:35:19.527",
                     "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return Ok(new Event(eventDate));
```

Comment: I've tried this but it still cuts off the end result. Returns: `"happenedAt": "2023-04-09T10:13:44"`

Comment: I believe it is the DateTime.ToString() that needs to be manipulated in terms of how ASP.NET serializes the JSON to return.

Comment: @3zy2umk22n Why don't you send the string (`"2023-04-09 09:35:19.527"`) as a response?

Comment: If you mean store it as a string then that's tricky as I perform date-like operations on the object. This should be a simple thing supported via ASP.NET I thought.